# How to open a box?

Tags: pressure, acoustics

Consider a box. How to open it by creating a pressure in the box, without contact?

For example, can I open it by a sound bomb?

Answer (score 1):

A [blast wave](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Blast_wave) of sufficient strength will be followed by a blast wind with negative pressure that sucks the box back toward the center of a nearby explosion.  The one-two punch of blast-wave [overpressure](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Overpressure) followed immediately by blast-wind negative pressure should pulverize the box and open it.

You can accomplish this with explosives or with an [acoustic shock wave](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shock_wave).  The acoustic wave, however, has very limited range.  Therefore, the source of the acoustic shock will need to be very close to the box.

Comment: sound bombs has nearly 190 dB, does it sufficient to make the opening pressure?

Comment: @bitkaf : What are you using this box for?

Answer (score 0):

The only way to create pressure inside the box, without touching it is to create a vacuum outside the box. Build an airtight container around the box find the fastest way to remove all the air. The box should explode.

Comment: How do you know the box itself is airtight?  If it is evacuated at the same time as the airtight container, it will not explode.

Comment: the box will be at 10.000 ft. if i send a signal from ground to explode the bomb, does it work?

Comment: @bitkaf what exactly are you asking us to help you engineer? Exploding things ten thousand feet above the ground has limited but significant and suspicious uses. Please elaborate on your plan.